# Hero Card Display & HTML support for MSTeams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am displaying a hero card which has several buttons. I would like to add a line break between the texts for each of the buttons. The channel that I am using is MSTeams

I have added HTML elements between the texts but that doesnt seem to help

```
List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                    string CurrentNumber = Convert.ToString(item.number);
                CardAction CardButton = new CardAction()
                {
                    Type = "imBack",
                    Title = ""+CurrentNumber + "\n" + "Short Description: "+ item.short_description + "<ul><li>" + "Opened on: "+item.opened_at + "</li><li>" + "Incident state: "+myDict[item.incident_state]+ "</li></ul>"+"",  //I tried this
                    Text = ""+CurrentNumber + "\n" + "Short Description: "+ item.short_description + "<ul><li>" + "Opened on: "+item.opened_at + "</li><li>" + "Incident state: "+myDict[item.incident_state]+ "</li></ul>"+"", //And this one too
                    Value = CurrentNumber
                    };
                    cardButtons.Add(CardButton);
             }

            HeroCard plCard = new HeroCard()
            {
                //Images = cardImages,
                Buttons = cardButtons,
            };
            // Create an Attachment by calling the
            // ToAttachment() method of the Hero Card                
            Attachment plAttachment = plCard.ToAttachment();
            // Attach the Attachment to the reply
            reply.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);
            // set the AttachmentLayout as 'list'
            reply.AttachmentLayout = "list";
```

While it works fine in the emulator if I add the "\n", in MS Teams, I dont get the same output.On hover, it appears that the text is appearing fine but not with MS Teams.
[image: On hover, it appears that the text is appearing fine but not with MS Teams]

Answer (score 0):

@Sash Sheen Teams supports [formatting in cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-format#html-formatting-for-simple-cards)  only in the Text property. It is not supported for buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are meant to be small and aren't supposed to have a lot of text on them. This is true across all channels.

My recommendation is to just include a short label on the button itself and have any additional required information elsewhere, like in the card's text. In your case, it seems like it would work out to just have the number on the button.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. Can this be added as a feature request? I mean why cannot we have multiple lines of text in a button since we already have limitations on the number of cards for certain type of channels supporting MSBOT framework.

Comment: @SashSheen - Like I said, buttons are meant to be small. This is by design. But if you'd like to submit a feature request, it looks like Teams has a UserVoice: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com